# Как задействовать GET параметр в RewriteRule htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Возможно ли "?" использовать в `RewriteRule`?

```
RewriteRule  ^dir_t/(.+)/\?ser$  dir.php?q=$1&type=ser  [L,QSA]
```

Comment: экранируйте: `\?`

Comment: Пробовал, не принимает $_GET

Comment: в реплейсменте без экранирования. в условии - с экранированием. вообще у вас нормально насчет вопроса, а вот .+ - мб не очень нормально [вот это](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5Edir_t%2F%28.%2B%29%2F%5C%3Fser%24&flags=&str=dir_t%2F55%2F44%2F%3Fser) ожидаемое поведение ?

Comment: Посмотрите про [QueryString](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString). У вас будет что-то типа:

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ser
    RewriteRule  ^dir_t/(.+)/$  dir.php?q=$1&type=ser  [L]